# Policy Kit isn't working properly?

Tags: polkit

Linux Mint 19 x64 with Cinnamon

Whenever I try to install a .deb by double clicking the file and clicking "Install Package" on the Package Installer popup, I get the following error:

[image: DBus.Error.NoReply]

> There seems to be a programming error in aptdaemon, the software that allows you to install/remove software and to perform other package management related tasks.
>
> org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message but without replying.

I can run `apt update` and `upgrade` just fine. I think something went wrong with an install I did awhile back using `dpkg` from the command line. I cannot find any details about how to fix this. Any ideas?

EDIT: I also can't install things from the Software Manager GUI. I've tried reinstalling both `mintinstall`, `mintupdate`, and `gdebi` but my situation has not changed after doing so. Can't uninstall through the GUI either.

EDIT 2: I've found that I can't open synaptic from the menu. If I run `synaptic-pkexec` from the command line I get the following output:

> Error checking for authorization com.ubuntu.pkexec.synaptic: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying

Which leads me to think my problem might have to do with policykit but I don't know enough about policykit. `policykit-desktop-privileges` seems to an aid for users in the admin or sudo groups that run common tasks as sudo for them automatically. When I double click a deb file and the gdebi-gtk no problem arises until it would normally ask for my sudo password.

How do I troubleshoot potential issues with policykit?

EDIT 3: The problem seems to be rooted in Policy Kit so I've edited the question. I have a stable install of Linux Mint 19 x64 on my laptop and have been comparing my desktop's behavior to the laptop. On my laptop I run `pkexec nano` and the UI pops up asking for my password for sudo and running nano when I give the password. On my server, where I'm having the problem, when I run `pkexec nano` instead of the UI popup I expect, I get the same output I get when running `synaptic-pkexec` (except it says com.ubuntu.pkexec.exec instead of synaptic).

From some googling it seems that the default policy kit is supposed to be `/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1`. When I run the file I get:

> ** (polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:13684): WARNING **: 10:10:40.701: Unable to register authentication agent: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: An authentication agent already exists for the given subject

I'm not sure if there's a way to find what is the current authentication agent. I do have a service called `polkit` that's active and doesn't seem to be throwing any errors. I've checked the log in `/var/log/auth.log` but it doesn't contain any errors. When I do the above `pkexec nano` the log prints the following:

> Aug  9 10:14:44 MyComputerName polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c2 (system bus name :1.56 [/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1], object path /org/gnome/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)

This feels like polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1 is active and running but apparently improperly.

I also find it weird that I can run `sudo apt update` and get prompted for my password properly (and it executes properly when given the password). I thought polkit would be in charge of that and it seems broken.

Comment: Did you download in Firefox and choose to open with Gdebi?

Comment: I don't use Firefox. I'm double clicking the file in my Downloads folder. The package is for GitKraken, it downloaded it's own .deb update for me to install.

Comment: simply use `apt install "package name"`. instead of downloading `.deb` file

Comment: What if my package isn't in the repo? GitKraken happens to be but there might be times I'd rather install a .deb file than add a PPA. Circumventing the problem isn't a fix.

Comment: @Jeremy31 I may have focused on the wrong part of your question. Yes, Gdebi is what opens.

Comment: Could you add the package name?

Comment: @GAD3R I've been updating my question recently. I don't think it's specific to the package manager at all. I think I just noticed a policy kit problem while using the package manager to install deb files I've downloaded from elsewhere. Starting from Edit #2 to the details I just added, I detail how I can't use `pkexec` to run synaptic or any executable.

Answer (score 5):

I'm on Debian with KDE.

I had the symptoms you had: when started from menu, `synaptics` would not show the usual authentication pop-up. In the terminal, `sudo synaptics` worked.

`journalctl` (polkit segmentation faults) and learning that menu entry `synaptics` actually runs `synaptics-pkexec` got me here.

On https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=302811 I read that someone managed to get rid of the issue by removing a file created while installing xRDP. Go to

`/etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/`

and remove

`02-allow-colord.conf`

It worked for me instantly even without restarting polkit (`sudo systemctl restart polkit.service`).

Comment: This solved an issue for me on Ubuntu 18.04 where policykit wasn't letting me format a USB drive. Thank you!